# Digital clock text stopped in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, time

```
final TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(
    Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
tw.setText(mydate);
```

is my Android application code, text displayed hour but hour stopped, why?

Comment: Because, you have to refresh it, when you want to display time. This code set it only once. You can use [TextClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html), or refresh your code every x seconds in infinitive thread.

Comment: "text displayed hour but hour stopped"; what do you mean by this?

Comment: how to i refresh it without use textclock

Comment: there is time and is true but hour time stopping when i launch app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, you have to refresh it, when you want to display time. This code set it only once. You can use [TextClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html), or refresh your code every x seconds in infinitive thread like this:

```
private Thread dateTimeThread;
private TextView tw;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (dateTimeThread != null) {
        dateTimeThread.interrupt();
        dateTimeThread = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    DateTimeRunner timeRunnable = new DateTimeRunner();
    dateTimeThread = new Thread(timeRunnable);
    dateTimeThread.start();
}

private void tickTime() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            tw.setText(mydate);
        }
    });
}

protected class DateTimeRunner implements Runnable {
    // @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                tickTime();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where i write this code?

Comment: In your Activity, where you are setting hours to textView.

Comment: this code is errored http://i.imgur.com/2jDl4Sm.png

Comment: I edited the answer, but this code is correct.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/7KZCgrj.png

Comment: Please, study Activity in Android and look at some examples how to add this code correctly. Because for me it is OK: http://i.imgur.com/pStn35R.png

Comment: i'm fixed problem. http://i.imgur.com/6ZyhntP.png but now there is a problem.

Comment: Yes, you have declared method onCreate twice. Copy code from this one to the first.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/MUPPUPc.png now i tried, there isn't error but app stopped working when i launched app.

Comment: Because setContentView in onCreate is missing

Answer (score 0):

You should put your refresh code in a auto refresh block like using Handler

```
 private void autoRfresh() {
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            //put your refresh code here
         }
     }, 500);
```

}

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/U2E93R4.png

Comment: Create a Handler object then do it ..